# Characteristic Sequence of Nilpotent Lie Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$).We consider the maps $ad(x)$ for $x \in L$ and write the Jordan form of $ad(x)$.Does it follow that it has at least one Jordan block of size 1 ? If NOT then is the same true if we take  $x \in L \setminus [LL]$  ? I tried some linear algebraic arguments but failed!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's indeed simple linear algebra.

Let $D$ be the line generated by $x$, let $I$ be the image of $\mathrm{ad}(x)$. Then $x\notin I$ (because $L$ is nilpotent). Hence there exists a hyperplane $H$ containing $I$ such that $x\notin H$. Then $L=D\oplus H$, $\mathrm{ad}(x)$ preserves $H$ and is $0$ on the line $D$, so this is a Jordan block of size 1.

Comment: Thanks for your ans and this is exactly what I was looking for. You mean $x \notin H$ ?I had tried the same thing but could NOT see why ad(x) preserves such a vector space complement  $H$ . But now I hope its clear. Am I right if I just consider $D \oplus I$ and take its vector space complement ,say $K$ then $L=D \oplus (I \oplus K)$ as the invariant space decomposition ??

Comment: I'm just using that given an endomorphism, every subspace containing the image is stable. I don't know what you call "its vector space complement" since it's not unique. You can choose a complement $K$ of $I$ in $H$, but usually it will not be stable (and there does not always exist a stable one). What for?...

Comment: I am not taking complement of $I$ but of $D \oplus I$ in $L$.Yes it might not be unique. But if we take any such complement ,say $K$, and consider $I \oplus K$ ,then my question is whether $I \oplus K$ an invariant subspace ?

Comment: Then it's just a way to restate my answer. It is trivially true that every subspace containing $I$ is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following idea can be made precise. If $L$ is abelian, then all $ad(x)$ are zero, hence the Jordan form consists of blocks of size $1$. Otherwise $L$ has the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra as a subalgebra. Let $x$ be a non-zero element of $L$. By Lie's Theorem we may assume there is a basis $e_1=x,e_2,\ldots ,e_n$ such that $ad(x)$ is lower-triangular and $[x,e_2]=e_3$, because of the Heisenberg Lie algebra. Then $ad(x)$ has a zero Jordan block of size $1$ in the left-upper corner.

Comment: It seems wrt the basis $(e_1, e_2 \ldots e_n)$ we get a lower triangular  Jordan form which is having two blocks of sizes 1 & $n-1$ . Actually this filiform Lie algebra is of nilindex $n-1$. So $ad(x)^{n-1}$ should always be zero.So we can not expect a full Jordan block in $ad(x)$ of size $n$ .

Comment: But thank you for your answer. I have been a follower  of your research .

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the answer, but it is still just an idea.